# Why the response doesn't return id in the below cypress test

Tags: javascript, cypress

Why the `response` doesn't return `id` in the below cypress test, `console.log()` printing as 'undefined'

```
describe('Hello', function() {
   it.only('Hello', function() {
   const getId = function() {
     cy.request('GET', 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/42')
       .then((response) => {
       //response.body is automatically serialized into JSON
       return response.body.id
        })
       }
      const user_Id = getId();
      console.log("This is my request"+user_Id);
   })
})
```

Comment: Can someone please remove the duplicate tag if possible.

Comment: You can ask the question again in a different way (e.g without the javascript tag)